# Use offset to remove the oldest post?

Tags: php, wordpress, offset

I have a function in my functions.php that creates a shortcode. The shortcode pulls the latest 10 posts from a particular category and displays them as a list. If there are less than 10 posts I don't want the oldest (first) post to show. Im using offset but it is removing the most recent post. How can I get it to remove the oldest post?

```
  // Category Shortcode - House Sitting
function dee_display_recent_housesitting() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page&'=> 10,
        'offset'=>  1,
        'cat'=> 2020,
    );  
    $dee_recent_housesitting = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $dee_recent_housesitting->have_posts() ):
        $dee_output = '<div class="box" <ul>';
        while ( $dee_recent_housesitting->have_posts() ) : $dee_recent_housesitting->the_post();
            $dee_output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
        endwhile; 
        $dee_output .= '</ul> </div>';
    endif;
    return $dee_output;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_shortcode( 'recent-housesitting', 'dee_display_recent_housesitting' );
```

Comment: be sure to sort by created date asc

Comment: Sorry are you able to elaborate? I'm quite new to some of this...

Comment: Sorted, Thank you, worked it out. Put order'=>ASC, in there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use order by date ASC, it is default to DESC.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page&'=> 10,
        'offset'=>  1,
        'cat'=> 2020,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'date'
    );
```